# Is there a way to specify which intents are active at specific points in a conversation using DialogFlow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am creating an interactive fiction game for the Google Assistant, and I want to move the story on after each choice the user makes.

I have created new intents to deal with each new scene, which look to see which choices have been made. I also want some other general intents to look for questions like, "What are my options?"

The problem I've encountered is that, when a user has moved on to a follow-up intent, they can still say a key word linked to a previous intent, and that intent provides an unwanted fulfilment.

What is the easiest way to disable certain intents from providing fulfilments in certain scenes, or of specifying which intents should be active at any time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get some control on which intents can be triggered by the user your can use Dialogflow's [context](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-overview) to set which intent can and cannot be triggered. You can set an Output Context on an intent, once that intent is triggered the output context will be active. While any contexts are active, Dialogflow will only match intents that are configured with input contexts that match the currently active contexts.

[image]

In the above image you can see an example, the CheckingBalance intent can only be triggered once an active context has been set in the CheckingInfo intent and while the context is active, Dialogflow will first look for any intents matching the context. For more info about setting input and output context. Have a look at the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-input-output).

Comment: Hi Jordi, thanks so much for your reply and it more than answered my question as it stood. I realised my original question was no where near specific enough. I tried to add the specifics to this comment, but I couldn't fit all the details, so have edited my question above. I noticed this problem with contexts in the original codelabs on the Google site when creating the Lucky Number app, but it becomes more pronounced in an interactive fiction game where intents need to be very specific to each scene. I'm sorry I've moved the goalposts.Thanks again for your input..

Comment: Alright, just FYI. Next time it is easier to accept the question and create a new question, then inform the person who is helping you about the new questions. It saves us and everyone else time with all the edits. :)

Comment: Hi Jordi. Yes, sorry about that. I realised that after I'd edited the question. I tried to revert it back to the original one, but wasn't sure how to do that as I didn't have the original saved.

Comment: For if you still would like to do it, next to the poster of the question, there is a section which tells you how long ago you edited the question. Here you can see the history. Each edit is shown with a number, here you should have a rollback option. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback